# How to show history of orders for user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I will pin some screenshots of my template and admin panel
I have history of orders in admin panel but when im trying to show title and img of order product in user profile in my template that`s not working and i got queryset
Im sorry for russian words in my site, i can rescreen my screenshots if you need that

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='orders', verbose_name='Заказы',
                             default=1)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя пользователя')
    email = models.EmailField()
    vk_or_telegram = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Ссылка для связи', default='vk.com')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Оплачено')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created',]
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Заказ {}'.format(self.id)


    def get_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    data = {
        'user_orders': user_orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/main_pages/profile.html', data)
```

order history template:

```
{% for item in user_orders %}
    {{ item }}
    {{ item.order.all }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Profile template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4zr.png)
[admin order panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok3tp.png)

Comment: I just want to get all orders with title name of product and his img

Comment: If you wish to add further detail to your question, please edit and update the question, Do not add comments with further clarifications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution, OrderItem has product, which is a ForeignKey for my product with title, content and img
Views.py changed for:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user_order_item = OrderItem.objects.all()

    data = {
        'user_orders': user_orders,
        'user_order_item': user_order_item,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/main_pages/profile.html', data)
```

Template:

```
{% if user_orders %}
   {% for item in user_order_item %}
    <p>{{ item.product.title }}</p>
    <p><img src="{{ item.product.photo.url }}" alt=""></p>
    % endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: ```     user_order_item = OrderItem.objects.all() ```
 it returns all of the order items, not the user's order items.

Comment: i have user_orders with filter and then in template im checking for this if you didnt see

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for storing the orders. This model should have fields for storing information about the order, such as the total cost, the date the order was placed, and the status of the order.

Create a view that will display the order history for a user. This view should retrieve all of the orders for the logged-in user from the database and pass them to a template.

Create a template to display the order history. This template should loop through the list of orders passed to it by the view and display the relevant information for each order.

Add a URL pattern to your Django project's urls.py file that maps to the view that displays the order history.

Add a link to the order history page in your application's navigation menu or elsewhere on the site.

Comment: but i got all models for that as well check "Order(models.Model)"

Answer (score 0):

In `user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)`
you have all of the user's order histories.
when sending these data to the front, don't use `{{ item.order.all }}`

each of your items is an order.

Comment: You mean i need to use just {{  item }} ?
But thats not working as well